# Can you use MapDotNet with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Is is possible to hook up Leaflet to a MapDotNet server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. [MapDotNet Features](http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/mapdotnet-ux-product-overview/mapdotnet-ux/mapdotnet-features)

MapDotNet offers a WMS service, that Leaflet can hook up. [MapDotNet WMS Service](http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/developers-center/mapdotnet-ux-8-help/49-mapdotnet-ux-8-web-services/108-wms-service)

And Leaflet can consume a WMS Service, see [this](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms)